# CodeIgniter and angular 4

Tags: angular, rest, codeigniter

Hey i am a newbie at angular 4 , currently i have a large project which is made using angular and jquery both and it is made on top of codeigniter framework(**NOT USING REST FRAMEWORK**).

**My question here is can i just import angular 4 as a library and start using it, just like i did with angular or do i have to rewrite/re-assemble entire code base in order for it to work.**

Currently i am using traditional codeigniter way to write my code( load view etc )...and use angular just the same way i did with jquery. But after learning angular 4 i feel like there is a need to change it and make my website into REST based but it is a lot of work. If it cant be done i will drop the plan. I just need to know if it is possible to integrate angular4 in my current website without rewriting/ re-assembling a lot of code?

Comment: Your previous app is in angularJS or angular 2 ?

Comment: its in angularJS!